# scipy.optimize.minimize returning [inf]

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to call `scipy.optimize.minimize` to minimize a function `poissonNegLogLikelihood`, which is defined as follows:

```
def poissonNegLogLikelihood(lam, y):

  Computes the negative log-likelihood for a Poisson random variable.

  Inputs:
  lam - float or array.  Parameter for the poisson distribution.
  y - float or array.  Observed data.

  Outputs:
  log_lik - float.  The negative log-likelihood for the data (y) with parameter (lam).

  Y = np.atleast_1d(y)
  LAM = np.atleast_1d(lam)
  log_lik = -np.sum(np.multiply(Y,np.log(LAM)) - gammaln(Y+1) - LAM)
  return log_lik
```

This function works fine, but when I try to use it as input to `scipy.optimize.minimize` it return [inf]. This is how I'm passing it:

```
data = np.array([1.0])
betas = np.array([0])
minimize(poissonNegLogLikelihood,betas,args=(data),jac=False)
```

Am I using the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing `np.log(LAM = beats = [0])` in `poissonNegLogLikelihood()` and `log(0)` is `-inf`. Therefore, it seems to me that your initial guess `betas` is the problem. You should test with adequate values.

Comment: This was it, thanks! I changed the initial condition to 1 and it worked fine.